# Кодировка темы письма с кириллицей

Tags: php, sendmail, zimbra

Всем доброго времени суток!

Такая ситуевина:
Есть сервер Zimbra (все настроено не мной, данных даже для просмотра логов никто не дает)

Есть скрипт на PHP, который должен выполнять отправку писем на этот сервер

Проблема: Если тему письма отправить латинницей(т.е. на английском языке) все работает, стоит поменять тему письма на кириллические символы: письма не идут (функция mail возвращает true, в ящике письма нет)

Мысли:

1. Письмо блокирует postfix( я так понял он стоит в корне зимбры )
2. Спам-блок( править конфиги мне не дают )
3. Беда с кодировкой (???)

```
protected $header = '';
protected $eol = '';
protected $infs = 'DOMAIN.ru';

public function __construct() {
    $os = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3));
    $this->eol = "\r\n";
}

protected function generateHeaders($subject) {
    $mailto = 'support@'.$this->infs;
    $name = '=?WINDOWS-1251?B?"'.base64_encode('TheSystem Domain').'"?='.'<'.$mailto.'>';
    $now = "uniqid(): %s\r\n".uniqid();
    $mime_boundary=md5(time()); 
    $this->headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$this->eol; 
    $this->headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"WINDOWS-1251\"".$this->eol;
    $this->headers .= 'From: '. $name.$this->eol; 
    $this->headers .= 'Reply-To:'. $name.$this->eol; 
    $this->headers .= 'Return-Path:"'. $name.$this->eol;
    $this->headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$this->eol;
    $this->headers .= "Subject: =?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding($subject, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($subject)))."?=".$this->eol;
    return $this->header;
}

protected function messagePrepare($msg) {
    return iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1251', $prepare.$msg);
}

protected function subjectPrepare($subject) {
    $this->generateHeaders($subject);
    return mb_convert_encoding($subject, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($subject));
}

public function send($address, $subject, $msg) {
    ini_set(sendmail_from, "TheSystem@DOMAIN.ru");
    $title = $this->subjectPrepare($subject);
    $mess = $this->messagePrepare($msg);
    echo base64_decode("0JfQsNC/0YDQvtGBINC90LAg0YDQtdCz0LjRgdGC0YDQsNGG0LjRjg==");
    var_dump($title, $mess, $this->headers);
    return mail($address, $title, $mess, $this->headers);
    ini_restore(sendmail_from);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошу прощения, решение найдено.

Ответ на вопрос:

```
$mail = new Mailer();
$mail->send('support@domain.ru', "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($title)."?=", $msg) );
```